# In Windows 7 Libraries, how do you hide the folder location subview to be like default Documents library?

Tags: windows-7, windows

All of the default libraries in Windows 7 do not show any subdivisions of where the files in the library are actually stored on disk.  But when you create a new custom library, the folders (even if there is only one folder) are "arranged" by folder location like so:

[image]

I would like to only see actual folders such as in the Documents library, and hide these subdivisions.  I tried changing the "Arrange by" setting at the top right, to various settings, but when I do that, the inner folders such as those in `C:\Users\nafieta\Downloads\Installers` in the picture are not shown, but their contents are shown, giving me a big mess of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click > Group By > None.